# Resposta saindo apenas true para todos elementos, ou false

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Estava resolvendo uma questão onde existe duas funções.

A primeira função é para saber se o valor é verdadeiro ou falso com dois parâmetros, se for igual ou menor que o segundo parâmetro vai ser verdadeiro se não, falso, retornando isso para o elemento.

A segunda função vai utilizar a primeira para usar de uma forma que escale, ex: `[true, false, true, true]`.

Coloquei valores para fim de teste porém não esta dando muito certo na hora de imprimir.

Se a `qntMinima` for valor 0 ou menor todos são verdadeiros, independente das condicionais, se for maior que 0, todos são falso.

A impressão da função, existe uma maneira de eu imprimir apenas o elemento que eu queira?

```js
function trueoufalse(horario, qntMinima) {
    var contagem = 0;
    for (var a = 0; a < horario.length; a++) {
        if (horario[a] <= 0) {
            contagem = contagem + 1;
        }
    }
    if (contagem >= qntMinima) {
        return true;
    }
    if (contagem < qntMinima) {
        return false;
    }
}

function a(dias, qntMinima) {
    var qntMinima = 2;
    var dias = [2, -300, 40, -3];
    var conc = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < dias.length; a++) {
        conc.push(trueoufalse(dias[a], qntMinima));
    }
    return conc;
}
console.log(a()); //false,false,false,false
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está passando `dias[a]` para a função, que no caso será um número. E dentro da função `trueoufalse` você tenta pegar o atributo `length` deste número, mas números não possuem `length`, e por isso o resultado de `horario.length` é `undefined`. Aí não entra no `for` e o contador sempre é zero.

Na verdade você fez uma confusão aí. Se a ideia da função `trueoufalse` é comparar apenas dois valores, e retornar se um é maior que outro, então ela deveria ser apenas assim:

```
function maiorOuIgual(valor, qntMinima) {
    return valor >= qntMinima;
}
```

Só isso, mais nada (até questiono se precisava mesmo de uma função só para isso, mas como parece ser um exercício que "exige" que se crie a função, então deixemos assim). Repare que se o retorno é um *booleano* (`true` ou `false`) eu posso retornar diretamente o resultado da comparação, já que toda comparação retorna um valor *booleano*. De maneira geral, uma expressão assim:

```
if (condicao) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Pode ser trocada por:

```
return condicao;
```

Também mudei o nome da função para algo um pouco melhor, pois na verdade `trueoufalse` é o retorno, mas **o que ela faz de fato** é verificar se o valor passado é maior ou igual à quantidade mínima informada. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Sendo assim, a funcão `a` também poderia mudar de nome. Outro detalhe é que você declara parâmetros que não são usados:

```
function a(dias, qntMinima) {
    var qntMinima = 2;
    var dias = [2, -300, 40, -3];
    ...
}
```

Ou seja, você passa as variáveis `dias` e `qntMinima`, mas logo nas primeiras linhas da função já sobrescreve os seus valores (ou seja, os parâmetros não serviram para nada). Então ou você declara a função sem parâmetros:

```
function a() {
    var qntMinima = 2;
    var dias = [2, -300, 40, -3];
    ...
}

a();
```

Ou você declara os parâmetros e passa os respectivos valores na chamada da função:

```
function a(dias, qntMinima) {
    // não sobrescreve dias e qntMinima
    ...
}

// chama a função passando os parâmetros
a([2, -300, 40, -3], 2);

// chama a função passando outros parâmetros
a([1, -30, 933], 15);
```

A vantagem da segunda forma é que a função fica bem genérica, podendo receber quaisquer valores (a primeira forma só vai funcionar para os valores que você colocou).

O problema é que o JavaScript é bem permissivo e não "dá erro" quando você passa uma quantidade de argumentos diferente do que foi declarado. Então cabe a nós, que estamos programando, prestar atenção a estes detalhes.

---

Sendo assim, uma solução seria:

```js
function maiorOuIgual(valor, qntMinima) {
    return valor >= qntMinima;
}

function verificarQuantidades(dias, qntMinima) {
    var conc = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < dias.length; a++) {
        conc.push(maiorOuIgual(dias[a], qntMinima));
    }
    return conc;
}

console.log(verificarQuantidades([2, -300, 40, -3], 2)); // [ true, false, true, false ]
console.log(verificarQuantidades([1, -30, 15, 2, 933], 15)); // [ false, false, true, false, true ]
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar o [método `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), que serve justamente para mapear cada valor do array para outro, retornando outro array com os resultados. Assim, você mapeia cada número para o respectivo resultado da comparação:

```js
function maiorOuIgual(valor, qntMinima) {
    return valor >= qntMinima;
}

function verificarQuantidades(dias, qntMinima) {
    return dias.map(n => maiorOuIgual(n, qntMinima));
}

console.log(verificarQuantidades([2, -300, 40, -3], 2)); // [ true, false, true, false ]
console.log(verificarQuantidades([1, -30, 15, 2, 933], 15)); // [ false, false, true, false, true ]
```

Caso a primeira função não seja "obrigatória", você também pode fazer tudo de uma vez:

```
function verificarQuantidades(dias, qntMinima) {
    return dias.map(n => n >= qntMinima);
}
```

Ou ainda, usando [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
function verificarQuantidades(dias, qntMinima) {
    let result = [];
    for (const n of dias) result.push(n >= qntMinima);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sua função `trueoufalse` recebe apenas 1 horário como argumento, portanto o `for` nunca vai executar. Basta fazer a comparação entre os números, dado que a função `a` já itera pelos elementos:

```js
function trueoufalse (horario, qntMinima) {

  if (horario >= qntMinima) {
    return true;
  }
  if (contagem<qntMinima) {
    return false;
  }
}

function a (dias,qntMinima) { 
  var qntMinima = 2;
  var dias = [2,-300,40,-3];
  var conc = []; 
    for (var a=0;a<dias.length;a++) {
      conc.push(trueoufalse(dias[a], qntMinima));
    }
  
  return conc;
}
console.log(a()); // [true, false, true, false]
```

Uma outra forma de fazer é utilizando a função `map`:

```js
function a (dias,qntMinima) { 
  var qntMinima = 2;
  var dias = [2,-300,40,-3];
  var conc = []; 

  conc = dias.map((horario) => horario >= qntMinima)
  
  return conc;
}
console.log(a());
```